# initializing multi-dim string arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

Stuck here trying to initialize an array (c#) using a loop. The number of rows will change depending. I need to get back two values that I am calculating earlier in the program startweek, and endweek. Lots of examples on building int arrays using loops but nothing I can find re dynamic strings and multi dim arrays.

Thanks

how do I set the values for col1 in string[,] arrayWeeks = new string[numWeeks, col1]; Is that clearer?

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Thanks for the clarification.)  You can do a multidimensional initializer like so:

```
string[,] arrayWeeks = new string[,] { { "1", "2" }, { "3", "4" }, { "5", "6" }, { "7", "8" } };
```

Or, if your array is jagged:

```
string[][] arrayWeeks = new string[][] 
{
    new string[] {"1","2","3"},
    new string[] {"4","5"},
    new string[] {"6","7"},
    new string[] {"8"}
};
```

If you're in a loop, I'm guessing you want jagged.  And instead of initializing with values, you may want to call `arrayWeeks[x] = new string[y];` where x is the row you're adding and y is the number of elements in that row.  Then you can set each value: `arrayWeeks[x][i] = ...` where you are setting the ith element in the row.  Your initial declaration of the array would be `string[][] arrayWeeks = new string[numRows][];`

So, to summarize, you probably want something that looks like this:

```
    int numRows = 2;
    string[][] arrayWeeks = new string[numRows][];
    arrayWeeks[0] = new string[2];
    arrayWeeks[0][0] = "hi";
    arrayWeeks[0][1] = "bye";
    arrayWeeks[1] = new string[1];
    arrayWeeks[1][0] = "aloha";
```

But, obviously, within your loop.

Answer (score 3):

There are two types of what you might call "multidimensional" arrays in C#. There are genuine [multidimensional arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx):

```
string[,] array = new string[4, 4];
array[0, 0] = "Hello, world!";
// etc.
```

There are also [jagged arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx). A jagged array an array whose elements are also arrays. The "rows" in a jagged array can be of different lengths. An important note with jagged arrays is that you have to manually initialize the "rows":

```
string[][] array = new string[4][];
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    array[i] = new string[4];
}
array[0][0] = "Hello, world!";
```

Answer (score 3):

If the number of rows change depending on some factor (not fixed), it would be better to use a container, such as a List (see [list on the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)). You can nest a list within a list to create a multi-dimensional list.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the conversation, but here is a jagged array example when you setting the size and data dynamically:

```
// rowCount from runtime data
stringArray = new string[rowCount][];

for (int index = 0; index < rowCount; index++)
{
    // columnCount from runtime data
    stringArray[index] = new string[columnCount];

    for (int index2 = 0; index2 < columnCount; index2++)
    {
        // value from runtime data
        stringArray[index][index2] = value;
    }
}
```